Sympy breaks regex in python?
I have the code:
import re
import math
#from sympy import * # breaks?
#x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
#init_printing(use_unicode=True)


def evaluate_expression(expr, variables):
    # Evaluate the expression using eval(), and provide the variables dictionary
    return eval(expr, variables)

def main():
    tools = """
<<<[eval("5"),a_x]>>>
<<<[eval("5+a_x"),ans]>>>
"""

    variables = {}
    lines = tools.strip().split("\n")

    for line in lines:
        # Extract the inner array using regular expression
        match = re.search(r'<<<\[(.*?),(\w+)\]>>>', line)
        if match:
            # Extract expression and variable name
            expr = match.group(1)
            var_name = match.group(2)

            # Evaluate expression
            value = evaluate_expression(expr, variables)

            # Update variables dictionary
            variables[var_name] = value

            # Check if 'ans' is defined
            if 'ans' in variables:
                print("ans =", variables['ans'])
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


If I dont import sympy, it runs fine, but if I do import sympy, it breaks, the re search no longer exists, no matter what I name variables. I dont get it?

sympy has re class, when you import all * you hide the re import. Import sympy first (or import only what you actually need from it)
from sympy import *
import re

# Output: ans = 10


From here math import breaks aswell, even if below the import *?

@VatsaPandey it probably hides something as well. Import only what you need.

you can also (for example if you need sympy's re) use as style like from sympy import re as re_sympy or simply import sympy and prefix with it
